# how to send parameters to an application while installing msi file silently

Tags: xml, command-line, powershell-3.0, silent-installer

I need to install an msi file silently, but some application needs some parameters (like ip address).so how to send the parameters to the application while installing the msi silently.

Comment: Could you provide us with more information

Answer (score 0):

Each msi installer has their own set of parameters that you can add when installing through command line.
Try to find a readme file online, or see if the help message exists by running something like  `installer.msi /?` or `./installer.msi --help`.